# Angular Routes not rendering child components, instead render parent component

Tags: angular, routes, angular-router

I want to create a nested route `movies/:id` However with my current configuration, when user navigates to `movies/1` the parent component is always rendered. I need `MovieDetailComponent` to render on `movies/1` url. Here is my configuration:

```js
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    component: HomeView
  },
  {
    path: 'movies',
    component: MoviesView,
    children: [{
      path: ':id',
      component: MovieDetailComponent
    }]
  },
  {
    path: 'not-found',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'not-found'
  }
];
```

I have tried adding `pathMatch: 'full'` to the parent component first and then child component, and then both. When I add `pathMach: 'full'` to the parent component, the child URL doesn't even get hit, when I add the `pathMatch: 'full'` just to the child component, only the parent component ever gets rendered even if the URL is `/movies/:id` Why is this happening?

When I moved the child path into its own route, not being nested, the component rendered correctly.

```js
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    component: HomeView
  },
  {
    path: 'movies',
    component: MoviesView
  },
  {
    path: 'movies:id',
    component: MovieDetailComponent
  } {
    path: 'not-found',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'not-found'
  }
];
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you have route that has a component and also a children field Angular will use that component's router outlet to place the children component DOM. So in your case you should have a router outlet in your **MoviesView** component:

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

If you want to have a different view when you go to `movies` and `movies/:id` you need to go with the second method. If you need now or in the future to have more than one extra route under the movies route I prefer to write it as

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeView },  
  { path: 'movies',
    children: [
    { path: '', component: MoviesView }
    { path: ':id', component: MovieDetailComponent }
  ]},
  { path: 'not-found', component: PageNotFoundComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'not-found'}
];
```

Also if you don't need the `movies` route (without the id) you can do:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeView },  
  { path: 'movies',
    children: [
    { path: ':id', component: MovieDetailComponent }
  ]},
  { path: 'not-found', component: PageNotFoundComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'not-found'}
];
```

Comment: I see, so in order to have one component be displayed at a time, I have to just put it as another route, instead of as a child route. Chile routes will always display inside parents then right?

Comment: Yes you're correct. But if you don't specify a component for the "parent" (so you remove the `component: MoviesView`) then it uses the first router outlet it finds in the chain (probably you only have one router outlet so it is going to be the one in your root component)

Comment: @O.MeeKoh I edited the answer to have an example for my previous comment

Comment: This is perfect, exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: I am glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `<router-outlet>` directives, you have to have one inside the **MoviesView** component.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Adding `<router-outlet>` inside MoviesView worked, however now both components are rendered when hitting movies/:id, how can I make it so only the MoviesDetailComponent gets displayed instead of both MoviesView and MoviesDetail?

Comment: @O.MeeKoh
Hm, you can do something like that then:


const routes: Routes = [
      ...,
        { path: 'movies', component: MoviesContainer,
           children: [
              { path: ':id', component: MovieDetailComponent },
              { path: '', component: MoviesView },
           ]
        }
     ...
];